# How can I add a 'is_logged_in' condition along with another if statement in django python?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

This is my views.py for search.

```
 @csrf_exempt
    def search(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            loc = request.POST.get('location')
            bussinessName = request.POST.get('bussinessName')
            d = {
                'name': name,
                'loc': loc,
                'bussinessName': bussinessName,

            }
            return render(request, "search.html", d);
        else:
        # do the thing you want to do in GET method

            return render(request,"search.html",{});
```

I need to add a session to get the id. This is how I am getting the id for my success page

```
def success(request):
    if('is_logged_in' in request.session):
        id = request.session['authToken'];
        return render(request,"success.html",{'uid':id});
    else:
        return render(request,"success.html",{});
```

HOW CAN I able to add this session in search. I am a beginner in Django and I do not have much idea about the same. Please help me to have a session for my search too..

Comment: What do you mean by "add this session in search"?

Comment: I need to add  if('is_logged_in' in request.session):
        id = request.session['authToken'];
        return render(request,"success.html",{'uid':id}); to my seach

Comment: Any specific reason for tagging jQuery/Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

after login, you can set session as

```
request.session['authToken'] = id
```

to check if the user is logged in or not just check if 'authToken' is a key in request session or not. So you here is the code

```
@csrf_exempt
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        loc = request.POST.get('location')
        bussinessName = request.POST.get('bussinessName')
        d = {
            'name': name,
            'loc': loc,
            'bussinessName': bussinessName,
            'is_logged_in': True if 'authToken' in request.session.keys() else False
        }
        return render(request, "search.html", d);
    else:
    # do the thing you want to do in GET method

        return render(request,"search.html",{});
```

So, if there is no session set for that user, 'is_logged_in' will go as False else True

Answer (score 0):

To check if someone is logged in, I would go with `request.user.is_authenticated`, relying on the Django auth framework.

Checkout https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users.

To set the `request.user` variable, I always use a form (with `username` and `password` fields) that posts to `/admin/login/?next={{ request.path }}`, to come back to the exact same page but then logged in.